# Java HashMap sorting using custom lambda comparator

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, hashmap, comparator

So I have a `LinkedHashMap` that has keys as a `Float[]` array and values as `LinkedList<LinkedList>` (nested lists). For each key, I try to sort the values by numeric order, which is obtained from comparing a float value within that nested list. In details:

```
// copy of an original hashmap 
LinkedHashMap<Float[], LinkedList<LinkedList>> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(attrMap);
```

Then the comparator:

```
// i is index of numeric (float) value I want to sort with
Comparator<LinkedList> comp = (a, b)-> ((Float) a.get(i)).compareTo((Float) b.get(i));
tempMap.get(keyObj).sort(comp);
```

This does not sort the map. How could I fix it?

EDIT2: Since it's tricky to replicate the actual code, here is my source code on  [github link](https://github.com/Phuongt994/rangedclassification). The code snippet lies within Analyser class, under biConvert() method.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post short but complete example which we could copy-paste to our machines and reproduce your problem (possibly by creating such example you will also find cause of your problem).

Comment: Your example doesn't compile, for instance on `l.append(..)`. Please try to post code which doesn't introduce errors unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Sorry but link can't be only source to code which doesn't work, especially when you want later to correct linked code which will invalidate your question. Purpose of Stack Overflow is to be searchable repository for future users, so if your question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce your problem within itself then I am afraid it is off-topic here.

Comment: Also if you expect from others to spend some time on helping you, you are expected to spend similar amount of time and effort (or more) to make helping you as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the sorting result to the same map

Comment: From what I remember `list.sort(comparator)` doesn't return new list, but rearranges one on which we invoked that method, so changes should be visible from anywhere where that list is used (including map which already holds that list).

Comment: excuse me, could you explain what do you want to sort? Floats or lists?

Comment: I am not the author of this question (so you may need to post that comment under question rather than your answer if you want author to be informed about it), but from what I see OP (original poster) want to sort list which contains other list (which probably contains floats). I see such list like table where first list contains rows, and second values for columns and OP wants to sort rows based on selected column.

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo, I have edited the question as you said. What you described is correct, since the code is to sort and analyse a given csv table (iris dataset as sample data). It gets messy as I need a mixture of data in a map (nested list of list of int-floats-string) and sorting nested list is more annoying than I thought.. would be really thankful if someone can point a mistake out!